# Trigonometry - SSS formula to calculate angle of Triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to calculate angle using Law of cosines, SSS formula of Triangle.

That is given three sides of triangle, calculate angle between sides.

When there is large difference between all sides of triangle i am not getting correct values

e.g. 564564465456456, 56564564646, 2121321313 are sides of triangle

i am getting cos A = -1328147089.07131
for which i am unable to calculate ARCCOS so i am not able to get exact value of angle.

e.g 8394050, 43341, 6163642 are sides of triangle

Please let me know how to solve this problem. **I want to get exact value of angle**
I am using formula a2 = b2 + c2 - 2bc cos A  ( here a2 = a square, Law of cosines formula ) 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: Remember to check feasibility, that no one side is greater than the sum of lengths of the other two sides ("triangle inequality").  This is violated by your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers cannot be the sides of a triangle, for they do not satisfy the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). For example,

$$8394050 > 43341 + 6163642$$

Comment: my triangle is that much large only. If i take sides as 5, 2, 1 then also CosA coming -5 and i am not able to calculate ArcSin and unable to get angle. please help me

Comment: $2+1<5$ $\implies$ this is not a triangle.